# Google OAuth 2.0 token API returns an undocumented field

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

As part of the OAuth 2.0 flow, I am sending a request from my backend to: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token HTTP/1.1`. My request is constructed as follows:
`code=<code>&state=<state>&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<cliend_secret>hd=<domain>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&grant_type=authorization_code`

The response I get is structured as follows:

```
{
  "access_token": <access_token>,
  "expires_in": <expires_in>,
  "scope": <scope>,
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "<id_token>"
}
```

Notice the field `id_token`. I could not find any mention for it on [Google's API docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code).

I suspect something has changed in the content of that field, which looks like this:

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub" <sub>,
  "hd": <domain>,
  "email": <email>>,
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": <hash>,
  "iat": 1695907170,
  "exp": 1695910770
}
```

specifically the content of the "sub" field.
But since it's undocumented, I don't think I'll be able to find anything about it on the release notes.

Any idea why it's undocumented and if any change has occured and if so why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did token is returned as part of sign-in or authencation. Also called open id connect.

Google apis uses Oauth2 to request authorization to access a users private data it will return an access token and a refresh token.

Wild guess you are sending openid, profile and or email scopes when requesting the user authorize your app.  or you are using some signin library when what you should be doing is using oauth2.

Comment: Since I'm trying to solve a bug in an existing code, I'm not 100% sure of the original author's intent. I'm trying to understand the meaning of the sub field inside the id token, but couldn't find any documentation about it. Do you happen to know and can direct me?

Comment: sub field also known as the subject field is the the internal user id for the user on google system.   check the rfc for open id connect.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!